# Regex: Match only first instance of a value

Tags: regex, r

I've looked through a ton of regex questions similar to mine, but all seem very complicated or don't work when I replace the value they are interested in (for instance a comma), with the value I'm interested in matching (underscore).

Basically, I want to match only the first underscore in each line of the following example:

As far as I can tell, 
     `_+?`
should work, but doesn't. Still matches all. Same for
     `_{1}`
should also work, but it matches all, not just the first as the quantifier specifies.

Example:

```
armsling_R_1_Group

armsling_R_1_Rank

armsling_R_2_Group

armsling_R_2_Rank

armsling_R_3_Group

armsling_R_3_Rank

armsling_R_4_Group

armsling_R_4_Rank

armsling_C_1

armsling_F_1

armsling_T_1

armsling_T_2

armsling_T_3

armsling_T_4
```

Edit: This is for R code, but I've been using regexr.com to test my expressions

Comment: Which lang/tool are you running?

Comment: This is for R code, but I've been using http://www.regexr.com/ to test my expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to separate these values (which are in one column) into two columns using `separate()` from `tidyr`. If I just use underscore it looks at the following ones as well.

Based off the comments in the posted answer, the following should work for you.

```
library(tidyr)
separate(x, y, c('icon', 'measure'), '_', extra = 'merge')

#        icon   measure
# 1  armsling R_1_Group
# 2  armsling  R_1_Rank
# 3  armsling R_2_Group
...
...
```

For a regular expression solution, I would utilize `strapply` from the [**gsubfn**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) package:

```
m <- strapply(as.character(x$y), '([^_]*)_(.*)', 
   ~ c(icon = x, measure = y), simplify = rbind)

X <- as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#        icon   measure
# 1  armsling R_1_Group
# 2  armsling  R_1_Rank
# 3  armsling R_2_Group
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm kicking myself that I didn't see that. That solves my immediate problem, however if anyone knows how to do this in Regex I'd still very much like to know whether it's possible for my own edification.